# drag'n'drop uploading images - support APIs issue

Tags: html, file-upload, drag-and-drop, xmlhttprequest

I'm using this [tutorial](http://html5doctor.com/drag-and-drop-to-server/) as a guide to implement my own HTML5 drag'n'drop -upload functionallity.

I also use File API, FileReader API and XHR2 API

I also included snippets from [this](http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload) source code to my code, to check for API support.

The weird thing is that I open the file with Chrome 28.0.1 and Firefox 23.0.1 that actually do support XHR2 and File API and I get

```
File API & FileReader API not supported

XHR2's FormData is not supported

XHR2's upload progress isn't supported
```

I dont understand what is wrong. I am a newbie with these APIs. Making a syntax error is one thing, but APIs not suppoerted? Where they should be? I just dont get it.

Thanks for your time

Here is my code

```
    <style>
    #holder { border: 10px dashed #ccc; width: 300px; min-height: 300px; margin: 20px auto;}
    #holder.hover { border: 10px dashed #0c0; }
    #holder img { display: block; margin: 10px auto; }
    #holder p { margin: 10px; font-size: 14px; }
    progress { width: 100%; }
    progress:after { content: '%'; }
    .fail { background: #c00; padding: 2px; color: #fff; }
    .hidden { display: none !important;}
    </style>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
//check for support API
    var holder = document.getElementById('holder'),
         tests = {
          filereader: typeof FileReader != 'undefined',
          dnd: 'draggable' in document.createElement('span'),
          formdata: !!window.FormData,
          progress: "upload" in new XMLHttpRequest
        }, 
        support = {
          filereader: document.getElementById('filereader'),
          formdata: document.getElementById('formdata'),
          progress: document.getElementById('progress')
        },
        acceptedTypes = {
          'image/png': true,
          'image/jpeg': true,
          'image/gif': true
        },
        progress = document.getElementById('uploadprogress'),
        fileupload = document.getElementById('upload');

    "filereader formdata progress".split(' ').forEach(function (api) {
      if (tests[api] === false) {
          alert('inside me, bad...');
        support[api].className = 'fail';
      } else {
        // FFS. I could have done el.hidden = true, but IE doesn't support
        // hidden, so I tried to create a polyfill that would extend the
        // Element.prototype, but then IE10 doesn't even give me access
        // to the Element object. Brilliant.
        support[api].className = 'hidden';
      }
    });

//preview files/images-give feedback to user
    function previewfile(file) {
      if (tests.filereader === true && acceptedTypes[file.type] === true) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {
          var image = new Image();
          image.src = event.target.result;
          image.width = 250; // a fake resize
          holder.appendChild(image);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }  else {
        holder.innerHTML += '<p>Uploaded ' + file.name + ' ' + (file.size ? (file.size/1024|0) + 'K' : '');
        alert(file.name);
        console.log(file);
      }
    }

    //read file from drop area
    function readfiles(files) {
        debugger;
        var formData = tests.formdata ? new FormData() : null;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          if (tests.formdata) formData.append('file', files[i]);
          alert(files[i].name);
          previewfile(files[i]);
        }

        // now send file
        if (tests.formdata) {
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', '/upload.php');
          xhr.onload = function() {
            progress.value = progress.innerHTML = 100;
          };

          if (tests.progress) {
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function (event) {
              if (event.lengthComputable) {
                var complete = (event.loaded / event.total * 100 | 0);
                progress.value = progress.innerHTML = complete;
              }
            }
          }

          xhr.send(formData);
        }
    }

    if (tests.dnd) { 

       holder.addEventListener('drop', ondrop, false); 
       holder.addEventListener('dragover', ondragover, false); 
       holder.addEventListener('dragend', ondragend, false); 

      holder.ondragover = function () { this.className = 'hover'; return false; };
      holder.ondragend = function () { this.className = ''; return false; };
      holder.ondrop = function (e) {
        this.className = '';
        e.preventDefault();
        readfiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
      }
    } else {
      fileupload.className = 'hidden';
      fileupload.querySelector('input').onchange = function () {
        readfiles(this.files);
      };
    }

    </script>


    <!-- the html -->
     <div id="holder">
      </div> 

      <p id="upload" class="hidden"><label>Drag &amp; drop not supported, but you can still upload via this input field:<br><input type="file"></label></p>
      <p id="filereader">File API &amp; FileReader API not supported</p>
      <p id="formdata">XHR2's FormData is not supported</p>
      <p id="progress">XHR2's upload progress isn't supported</p>
      <p>Upload progress: <progress id="uploadprogress" min="0" max="100" value="0">0</progress></p>
      <p>Drag an image from your desktop on to the drop zone above to see the browser both render the preview, but also upload automatically to this server.</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

Basically, javascript is trying to access html that doesn't exist yet.

**Solution**

This can be solved by running the javascript after the html has loaded.

There are many ways to do this:

- Put the javascript into script tags and place under the html.
- Place the javascript into it's own file and place this (`<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`) under the html.
- Put the javascript into a function and then add `onload="functionName();"` to the body tag.
- Use jQuery to only run the code once the document is "ready", for example `$(document).ready(function () { //code goes here });`
- Many other ways that we don't really need to get into just yet.

**Let's test this to be sure**

The code you provided gives this error `TypeError: support[api] is null on line 44`.

For a quick test I added this `console.log('api',api);` above line 44.

So lines 44 & 45 looked like this:

```
console.log('api',api);
support[api].className = 'hidden';
```

Console log output:

```
api filereader
TypeError: support[api] is null
```

Having another look at the code, we can see `support[filereader]` is set on line 23

```
support = {
          filereader: document.getElementById('filereader'),
```

So api = document.getElementById('filereader'), which happens to be null. That means the javascript can't find any elements where id="filereader".

But we know it exists by looking at line 126

```
<p id="filereader">File API &amp; FileReader API not supported</p>
```

So perhaps javascript can't access it because it has loaded onto the page yet.

Let's try putting the javascript below the html... yay now it works!

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Yes, thanks, it helped. Thanks for your time. Amazing anser.  So detailed